# Using two programming languages with the same file extension

Tags: directory-local-variables, auto-mode-alist

I am just starting to set up a perl environment in emacs but the problem is that I already program with prolog and both languages use the `.pl` file extension. I have two directory `~/src/prolog` and `~/src/perl` where I store code for the respective languages. Currently I only have this line in my init:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.pl$" . prolog-mode))
                               auto-mode-alist))
```

How can I tell emacs that `.pl` files in the `~/src/prolog` directory should use prolog-mode while the `.pl` files in `~/src/perl` should use cperl-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lucky that the files for the different languages are segregated by directory like that.

You can define directory-local values for variable `auto-mode-alist`.

See the Elisp manual, node [Directory Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html).

As the intro text of that node says:

> This is useful when the files in the directory belong to some “project” and
> therefore share the same local variables.

Comment: Won't that shadow all other entries on the list, though?